# Multiplying uneven datasets

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I am trying to interact the log of distance with the tariff rates on different countries but my data frames are of slightly different dimension. The first data frame is

```
'data.frame':   265 obs. of  32 variables:
```

and the second data frame is

```
'data.frame':   263 obs. of  32 variables:
```

I have been unable to find where they differ but my professor says that in STATA their are workarounds that should also be found in R. What work arounds would you use?

Comment: some row ids? Then you can inner-join tables. If you give me more info i can write a suited answer for you :)

Comment: The row ids are the same, I am looking at 264 countries over 32 years, 1987-2017.

Comment: Looks like you're loooking for anti_join? Take a look the example at: http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of preparing data for use in a regression or elsewhere is to put it all into the same dataframe using a merge.  You can either drop rows that are in one and not the other, or include them and have `NA` in their spots from the smaller dataset.  In a regression, observations with `NA` will be thrown out so it doesn't matter which you choose.

Let's say `First` is your dataframe with 265 observations and `Second` is your dataframe with 263.  In both dataframes, you have a column called "Year" that you will use to match.  Make sure there are no missing values in this column.

```
FinalData <- merge(First,Second,by="Year")
```

By default this will drop rows that are missing in either dataset. Then do your regression using `FinalData` as your input to `lm()` and you won't have any errors.